# How do you create an HTMLDocument from a string in Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla, dom

I have a small [POW](http://wiki.davidkellogg.com/)-based application that stores data as HTML files. Currently to read these files I open them in a new tab, but I'd like to reserve tabs for pages that are open for longer periods of time, and remove clutter from the history and the recently closed tabs list.

Comment: Not sure if it helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM

Comment: Thanks! Shows how much of a noob I am at searching the fine web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then I put my comment as an answer ;)

Have a look at [*HTML to DOM*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/HTML_to_DOM).

Btw. if I want to search for something Firefox addon related, I always search for `mdc other terms`. This will most likely find resources on the MDC sites...

Comment: MDC also has its own built-in search, but for some reason it seems to stop working periodically. By the way, don't forget that MDC is a wiki so you can take a few minutes to improve it as you're using it.